# как поменять фон кнопки? он не меняется при валидации

Tags: javascript, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function checkParams() {
  var width = $('.input_first').val();
  var height = $('.input_second').val();
  var button = document.querySelector('.button');

  if (width.length != 0 && height.length != 0) {
    $('.next').removeAttr('disabled');
    button.style.background = 'url(/)'

  } else {
    $('submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required type="text" name="text" placeholder="0" class="input_first" onkeyup="checkParams()">
<input onkeyup="checkParams()" required type="text" name="text2" placeholder="0" class="input_second">
<div class="button_cor">
  <input disabled="disabled" type="submit" name="Next" value="ДАЛЕЕ" class="next">
</div>
```

Путь к картинкам через CSS такой `background:url("../images/png/next_disabled.png");`

Comment: `$('submit')` - это что?

Comment: я не разбираюсь, просто через $('.button') у меня не работало ничего с сменой цвета bg

Comment: $('submit') это на событие submit насколько я понимаю, я просто это с сайта взял и скопировал

Comment: покажите html кнопки, отредактируйте вопрос

Comment: готово, отредактировал

Comment: В консоли браузера есть ошибки. Добавьте их в вопрос.

Comment: нету в консоли ошибок...

Comment: Не спорьте. Ошибки есть. Добавьте их в вопрос.

Comment: да нет, тут проблема именно в button.style.background="";

Comment: потому что пропадать-пропадает background а вот новый не появляется, в этом проблема

Comment: Я уже сделал для Вас работающий пример в Вашем вопросе. Ошибки есть.

Comment: не могу понять где ошибки...

Comment: ошибка в том, что не выводит картинку, а не что disabled не меняет, мне нужно помочь именно с button.style.background=я не знаю что тут писать и как

Comment: Нажмите в вопросе кнопку "Выполнить код".

Comment: мне нужно не цвет сделать, а фото, я же сто раз говорил, с цветом у меня и так получается все!

Comment: Нажмите **в вопросе** кнопку "Выполнить код".

Comment: я понял, у вас работает, но у меня не хочет искаться путь, как в css,он просто тупо не ищется и все

Answer (score 3):

```js
function checkParams() {
  var width = $('.input_first').val();
  var height = $('.input_second').val();

  if (width.length != 0 && height.length != 0) {
    $('.next').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.next').css({ 'background-image': 'url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png")' });
  } else {
    $('.next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.next').css({ 'background-image': '' });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required type="text" name="text" placeholder="0" class="input_first" onkeyup="checkParams()">
<input onkeyup="checkParams()" required type="text" name="text2" placeholder="0" class="input_second">
<div class="button_cor">
  <input disabled="disabled" type="submit" name="Next" value="ДАЛЕЕ" class="next" style="width:400px;height:200px;" onclick="console.log('test')">
</div>
```